# failing on OSError libgssapi_krb5.so: cannot open shared object file while installing using pip python 3.11

Tags: python, pip, python-3.11

I'm trying to install requests-kerberos package `pip install requests-kerberos`, but failing on
`OSError: ...:/libgssapi_krb5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have libgssapi_krb5.so in my ../python/lib/. I have tried to add the ../python/lib/ to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH but no success.

I'm using python 3.11.1 version

what can be the issue ? and how come it could not found although LD_LIBRARY_PATH include the lib ?

full er

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "my_area/python_tst/my_py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "my_area/python_tst/my_py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "my_area/python_tst/my_py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4fyocus/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4fyocus/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4fyocus/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 206, in <module>
    File "python3/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  OSError: python3/3.11.1/lib64:python3/3.11.1/lib:python3/3.11.1/lib64:python3/3.11.1/lib:python3/3.11.1/lib:python3/3.11.1/lib64:/libgssapi_krb5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: my_area/python_tst/my_py/bin/python3 my_area/python_tst/my_py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpcq6mx3_f
  cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l9aynml0/gssapi_40233975a0f24def9d5db604f4e4b0bd
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you did install `krb5-config` but not `libkrb5-dev`
Try to `sudo apt install krb5-config libkrb5-dev` to be sure. I manage to install `requests-kerberos` in my Kunbutu 23.03.  If it doesn't work please provide the full info on pip with `pip install requests-kerberos -v`.

Comment: thanks @RaiZy_Style, anyway to install it through python ? (I don't have sudo privilages in my machine), added the kerberos log from the issue. I have installed krb5 btw

Comment: I don't think it's possible without sudo, sorry. You need admin privileges to install this

Comment: but why is it needed ? at the end it is looking for the gssapi sofile and it does exist in python lib path

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think `libkrb5-dev` will install header and .so file like the one you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me this error I got when I worked on **csh** xterm, when I moved to **bash** xterm everything worked!!!